# Creating a complex entity with 1:n relation and one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have been asked to update a CRM system for a sports club that's been built using MVC Entity Framework. The system works, right now, by allowing staff at the club to create a core account to which you can add children and notes. These are the core classes

**Account Class**

```
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string TownCity { get; set; }
        public string RegionCounty { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SecondaryContact> SecondaryContacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<JobTask> JobTasks { get; set; } 
    }
```

**Child Class**

```
    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public string MedicalConditions { get; set; }
        public int SchoolYear { get; set; }
        public MembershipTypes MembershipType { get; set; }
        public AccountStatusTypes AccountStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Session> AttendedSessions { get; set; } 
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
```

At the moment, users at the firms office create an account, then add children to the account; having an account in place is a prerequisite for creating a child.

The management at the company are wanting to roll out a new, customer facing front end for their website on which customers can register and pay for their children to join the sports club. However, they've also presented me with a new process "flow" in which all the information must be taken on one page. So asking clients to create an account, then asking them to add their children one by one, (the same as the office staff do in their admin panel), is out of the question.

I suppose the core question is, is it possible to create a single view that would populate these two entities, or rather, can I add to the list of children in the account from a view? Bearing in mind that an account might possibly have multiple children? I've looked over SO for similar situations but it would seem that everything that's close to what I'm looking for is adding data that's already predefined.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Account` as the ViewModel and use the `Children` property to submit the created children - either by "pre-filling" the collection with empty children or by offering some kind of "add"-function (which reloads the page with the same account but one additional empty child in the collection).

In the view you can add input elements for the children by using a `for` loop - `foreach` does not work, as the model-binder needs the index variable to re-create the collection on post-back:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; ++i)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Children[i].FirstName)
    @* ...and so on... *@
}
```

I use such a construct in my application and it works fine.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I have had to change the Icollection<Child> to a List<Child> but this seems to be doing the trick.

I had thought originally that I would be bound by the need to create the account first but this a good solution. Thanks for you help and advice!